# Combining two rows in sql

Tags: sql, select

I have a really hard time figuring this out. I got one table called `voeding` and two rows `plantaardig` and `insecten` with data. Also check the image below to illustrate my question.

[image]

Which query should I use to find out which type of `voeding` (`plantaardig` and `insecten` together) is most used?

*To give some backgroud. The use case is which type of food is most eaten by reptiles*

Comment: Try this `select plantaardig, insecten , count(*)
from voeding
group by plantaardig,insecten 
order by count(*) desc`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` like

```
select plantaardig, count(plantaardig) as count1
from voeding
group by plantaardig
```

In case you want to mix then both then use `UNION` like

```
select * from (
select plantaardig as Foodee, count(plantaardig) as count1
from voeding
group by plantaardig

UNION

select insecten, count(insecten) 
from voeding
group by insecten ) xxx order by count1 desc;
```

Comment: You can also `ORDER BY count1 desc` to get the most common foods at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to query that returns the plantaardig with the most insecten.

The following query should do the trick:

```
SELECT plantaardig
FROM Voeding
GROUP BY plantaardig
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM Voeding
                        GROUP BY plantaardig)
```

**EDIT**

To get the insecten as well you can do the following:

```
SELECT V.plantaardig, V.insecten
FROM Voeding AS V JOIN (SELECT plantaardig
                        FROM Voeding
                        GROUP BY plantaardig
                        HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                FROM Voeding
                                                GROUP BY plantaardig)) AS t
     ON V.plantaardig = t.plantaardig
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean combining plantaardig and insecten.

Comment: @stevv I added insecten